# How do i make Text in my longtable move away from borders

Tags: longtable, alignment

Basically I got this code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.5mm}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{18pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.5}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{url}

\setlength\arrayrulewidth{1pt}
\setlength\tabcolsep{1pt}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}

\newenvironment{mylongtable}[2]{%
  \begin{longtable}{@{\hspace{1em}}#1@{}}
  #2}
  {
  \end{longtable}%
}\setlength\columnwidth{1pt}
\setlength\columnsep{10pt}
\newcommand\myLTleftcolumnwidth{\dimexpr\textwidth*0.1}
\newcommand\myvline{\vrule width 1pt}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}


\begin{document}

\begin{mylongtable}{@{}
>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.6\columnwidth} |
>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.4\columnwidth}@{}}
\toprule

\begin{minipage}[b]{\linewidth}\raggedright
\large
Gruppenrichtlinieneinstellung
\end{minipage} & \begin{minipage}[b]{\linewidth}\raggedright

\large
Empfohlene Option
\end{minipage} \\
\endhead

\emph{Pfad:}
\path{Computer Configuration\Policies\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Microsoft Defender Application Guard} & \\
Allow camera and microphone access in Microsoft Defender Application Guard & Disabled \\
Allow auditing events in Microsoft Defender Application Guard & Enabled \\
Allow data persistence for Microsoft Defender Application Guard & Disabled \\

\end{mylongtable}


\end{document}
```

[image: My Longtable looks like this]

At the moment basically everything is aligned left and glued to the border which looks really bad in my opinion.

My question is:
How do I move everything in every single cell to the right by let's say 1em?
(sorry for the awful code, started doing LaTeX 3 days ago)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please add a small, but reproducible test document. We have no idea how your `mylongtable` environment might be defined.

Comment: If I guess enough packages etc to make your code compilable, I don't get anything resembling your image.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I added a minimal working example, could you please look over it and try to guide me in the right direction?

Comment: @Ezmo I still don't get the image you show, but with `\setlength\tabcolsep{1pt}` you basically remove all space between the edge of the cell and the text.

Comment: tables normally have some padding around the cells but you used `@{}` to remove that, which is why the first column is flush to the margin

Comment: also your `p` columns are too wide, they already add up to `\linewidth` not allowing for `\tabcolsep` or `@{\hspace{1em}`

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz thank you! Got fixed!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you so much for the information!